# AngularJS method invocation with parameters

Tags: angularjs, method-invocation

I'm working on someone else's code and I don't fully understand it yet. Besides, I'm fairly new to AngularJS.

They have a class that looks like this:

```
return vm.item[vm.function](request).$promise.then(function (data) {
    ...
});
```

When my vm.function has no parameters, it works perfectly. I just do

```
vm.function = "myFunction"
```

and myFunction gets called as expected.

However, now I need to call a function that has an "id" parameter. I have already tried

```
vm.function = "myFunction(0)"
vm.function = "myfunction({id:0})"
```

And even adding an "id" element to the "request" var, but no result so far.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Hi David, allow me to ask you somethings regarding the question... i would guest that "vm" is a controller, and "function" is one its properties. Is `function` a directive's parameter binded to the controller? Is of type function `&`? From where you where do you want to invoke that function?. I Have use angular a lot, and never has to deal with something like `vm.item[vm.function](request).$promise.then(function (data)`.. :S

Comment: Hi Victor, I'm only trying to fix a small thing in this code, so it's not worth changing the whole structure of the code just for this. It's not my code and I don't know a lot of AngularJS, so I can't really tell you whether this is well structured or not. This line is used to standarize the way lists data is obtained in the app. From wherever you need to get data from an api in a list form, you use this class, which calls the function you specify. Item is usually a service and function is the service method you want to invoke

Comment: jaja, allow me to clarify that i wouldn't say that i know a lot, i say i use it a lot,... so you are using a map to call functions based on the type of data you want to fetch is OK, i see that, eventually, you got the problem of the arguments (not all the fetch-routines has the same arguments <- quite a problem that...), so the problem was in the calling code, so changing the `vm.item[vm.function](request)`to `vm.item[vm.function](request,id)` solves everybody problem, right?; maybe you could write more generally `vm.item[vm.function](request,params)`,params would containts the additional data

Comment: What I did (although I misght still change it later) was adding a structure "params" that is empty by default (so that I wouldn't have to change any other classes that don't use params) and then merge it with the "request" structure at the invocation time. This way, I can have, in my other class, vm.params = { id: "16" }, and now it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vm.function` is simply the name of the function, it says nothing of the parameters. Let's break down what's going on here.

```
vm.function = 'myFunction';

vm.item[vm.function](request)
```

translates to

```
vm.item['myFunction'](request)
```

which is equivalent to

```
vm.item.myFunction(request)
```

As you can see, it's already passing a `request` parameter. To add another, you'd simply do:

```
vm.item[vm.function](request, id)
```

Keep in mind when using this pattern that your dynamic function signatures must be compatible. If they begin to diverge (as you say, you're editing someone else's code) you should refactor to handle this in a different way.